# Displaying taxonomy term instead of category in title

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

To begin with, I really suck at Wordpress.

I have the following code which displays the category of each post in the search results:

```
<?php 
   $category = get_the_category();
   if ($category ) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category[0]->term_id ) . '" title="' . $category[0]->name . '" ' . '>' . $category[0]->name.'</a>';
        if(isset($category[1])){
           echo ' ...';
        }
   }
?>
```

What I want to do is replace the category with the term name of whatever taxonomy the posts happens to have. I've looked at a bunch of similar questions but I can't get it to work.

I guess it has something to do with this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term but due to my limited PHP skills I get stuck.

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your after displaying the terms/term for each post you can use get_the_terms.

```html
// Get taxonomy terms specifc to current post
$terms =  get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'your-taxonomy-name-here' );

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo '&nbsp;<a href="' .esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ). $term->slug . '" title="' . $term->name . '" ' . '>' . $term->name .'</a> &nbsp;';
}
```

All you need to do is replace 'your-taxonomy-name-here' with the name of your taxonomy and style the output to your liking.

Comment: Cool, would it be possible to tweak this so it looks up which taxonomy the post has?

Comment: It currently is finding all the taxonomies of the current post. What else what you want to do?

Comment: "$terms =  get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'your-taxonomy-name-here' );"

This part is what I'm thinking of. The posts being listed has one of many taxonomies so there's not just one I can replace for. I might be misunderstanding something (I usually do when it comes to coding)

Comment: Ahh ok I understand now, so you have multiple taxonomies you want the post to display terms from them all?

Comment: Try : $multi_terms = wp_get_post_terms ($post->ID , array('your-taxonomy-one','your-taxonomy-two','your-taxonomy-three') );